# Command Prompt and Installer Not Synced

Tags: visual-studio-2010, batch-file, command-line, installation, setup-project

How can I sync the command line to the setup project installer that it will not proceed until the task of the command line is done?

The installer needs to run BATCH scripts and it needs to log on to the database credentials. But even before logging on to the database, the installer still proceeds and finish the installation process.

[image: Figure 1.0]

Answer (score 0):

You could give a bit more context, but in general the answer is don't use bat files. You could have a custom action VB script that runs the external executeables (if that's what they are) and waits for them to finish. In general, whenever bat files show up during an install it's a red flag that something isn't right in the design. Usernames can be entered in UI dialogs at the front, for example, and passed to custom action programs; also many clients like silent installs where property values (like a username) can be passed on the msiexec command line and again get passed into a custom action, and it all just works - I suspect your install cannot be run silently because you are collecting a user name at the end of the install in a custom action.